# Seltlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese") cant read accents from keyboard input. C

Tags: c

I am using setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese") so my program can read brazillian portuguese accents worlds like "joão" from a text file and print it at screen, and it works fine for this purpose. But when i try to input a word like "joão" from the keyboard and using gets() or scanf() the string saved is something different from the input . Any advices ?

Comment: The locale doesn't directly affect what you can type. You probably want output to be UTF-8 (or at least for the terminal and the locale to agree) but for input, it depends a lot on the input layer. Anyway, I don't think `"Portuguese"` is a valid locale; try `pt_BR.UTF-8`.

Comment: Which source character set and which environemtn character set do you use? Which encoding? Which does your terminal use? Which functions do you use for input/output? etc.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the help. That works for the keyboard input problem, but it fails to read the words of the text file .

Comment: Without access to either the file or an adequate description of its contents, nor the code which fails to read it, I don't think we can add anything more here.  Update your question with pertinent detail if you want detailed help.  Answering @Olaf's questions would be a good start, but probably still not enough.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure how to answer all of those, sorry for my lack of knowledge. All I can say is the text file was encoding is ASCI according to notepad++, and i'm using windows 7 32bit, dev c

Comment: Ok guys, when I get back home from class I will elaborate my question,with more detailed and specific informations. Thanks for the help

Comment: ASCII is a 7 bit code. There will be no accented letters or other special symbols available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting terminal input, it is rarely correct to use `setlocale` in any way other than

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

That will set the program's locale to the environment's locale. Normally, the locale setting in the interactive environment corresponds to the configuration of the terminal, so it represents the expectation of the interactive user. Changing the program's locale has no effect on the terminal [Note 1], so if you do change it, it will simply mean that the program's locale no longer corresponds to the user's expectations.

It would be correct to `setlocale` for file input *if* you provide some mechanism to specify the environment for the file [Note 2]. In Unix, however, the simplest way for the user to specify that is on the command-line:

```
LC_ALL=pt_BR.utf8 ./my_command the_portuguese_file.utf8
```

For Windows, you may want to provide a different mechanism to communicate the file's locale to the program. But in the absence of such a declaration, using the locale configured in the environment will usually be the correct option.

The one exception to the above is programs which prefer to be locale-unaware, which may wish to set the locale to `"C"` (or `"POSIX"`, but `"C"` does not require a Posix-compatible `setlocale`). That can be useful to do as a form of self-documentation, but it is not necessary because a program which does not call `setlocale` at all will be executed in the `"C"` locale (on most operating systems).

---

#### Notes

1. In most cases, changing the environment's locale by modifying the value of the environment variable `LC_ALL` also has not effect on the terminal configuration. Indeed, the terminal may not even be part of the environment; for example, if you have a remote ssh/telnet session, or the GUI equivalent. A user should first configure their terminal according to their expectations, and then configure their environment to correspond; they will expect utility programs they run to respect the environment setting.
2. Aside from the strings `"C"`, `"POSIX"` and `""`, there are no standards which will let you even know what possible locale names are, which is yet another reason not to try to set the locale except when the user has asked you to.